# Removing off trading days from Plotly in candlestick charts

Tags: python, charts, plotly, finance, quantitative-finance

As there's no trading on Saturday and Sunday in stock markets, stock chart should be plotted without showing a gap on these two days as there is no data for them.

 In plotly, those 2 days (or any holiday) are shown as a horizontal gap on the chart which is not correct as this sample: 
https://plotly.com/python/candlestick-charts/ 
Any idea about how to fix that

[photo for the gap that is required to be removed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/408Qm.png)